# Why Java is not getting installed in my docker image using Postgres docker hub image

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

What I would like is to add Java (installation and JAVA_HOME) in an image.

I'm using this postgres dockerfile: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/tree/master/9.6

Which I updated with the following :

```
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install wget
RUN apt-get -y install sudo

RUN /bin/mkdir /usr/lib/jvm
RUN wget https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/9/GPL/openjdk-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz -O /tmp/openjdk-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
RUN sudo tar xfvz /tmp/openjdk-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz --directory /usr/lib/jvm
RUN rm -f /tmp/openjdk-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
ENV JAVA_HOME /etc/alternatives/jre
```

Please note that I'm beginner so if something is obvious for you it may not be for me.

The issue is that, /usr/lib/jvm is not created thus java is not installed and also JAVA_HOME is empty when I run the image.

When I execute manually the instructions, it works, but I would like to make my dockerfile working.

Comment: You'd almost always run your database and application in two separate containers.  This would let you build your application image `FROM openjdk:11` to use [the Docker Hub `openjdk` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk) with the JRE preinstalled.  Docker's [sample applications](https://docs.docker.com/samples/) include [an end-to-end Java lab](https://github.com/docker/labs/tree/master/developer-tools/java/) that has a sample Docker Compose setup.

Comment: Nested directory creation needs -P switch
RUN bash -c 'mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm'

and 

You are not installing java in the below location, what you are trying ot set here.
ENV JAVA_HOME /etc/alternatives/jre